# distance between formula and note

Tags: notes

I am trying to decrease the distance between the main formula and the object.
you can find Here the result what I aimed for
[image]

and what I actually recieved
[image]
and the code below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}   %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{fontspec}      %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}  %% свойства шрифтов по умолчанию
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman} %% задаёт основной шрифт документа
\setsansfont{Comic Sans MS}                    %% задаёт шрифт без засечек
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\ensuremath{\varepsilon}}
\renewcommand{\phi}{\ensuremath{\varphi}}
\renewcommand{\kappa}{\ensuremath{\varkappa}}
\renewcommand{\le}{\ensuremath{\leqslant}}
\renewcommand{\leq}{\ensuremath{\leqslant}}
\renewcommand{\ge}{\ensuremath{\geqslant}}
\renewcommand{\geq}{\ensuremath{\geqslant}}
\renewcommand{\emptyset}{\varnothing}

%%% Дополнительная работа с математикой
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % AMS
\usepackage{icomma} % "Умная" запятая: $0,2$ --- число, $0, 2$ --- перечисление

%% Номера формул
%\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} % Показывать номера только у тех формул, на которые есть \eqref{} в тексте.
%\usepackage{leqno} % Нумерация формул слева

%% Свои команды
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{\mathop{sgn}}

%% Перенос знаков в формулах (по Львовскому)
\newcommand*{\hm}[1]{#1\nobreak\discretionary{}
{\hbox{$\mathsurround=0pt #1$}}{}}

%%% Работа с картинками
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Для вставки рисунков
\graphicspath{{images/}{images2/}}  % папки с картинками
\setlength\fboxsep{3pt} % Отступ рамки \fbox{} от рисунка
\setlength\fboxrule{1pt} % Толщина линий рамки \fbox{}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Обтекание рисунков текстом

%%% Работа с таблицами
\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,booktabs} % Дополнительная работа с таблицами
\usepackage{longtable}  % Длинные таблицы
\usepackage{multirow} % Слияние строк в таблице

%%% Теоремы
\theoremstyle{plain} % Это стиль по умолчанию, его можно не переопределять.
\newtheorem{theorem}{Теорема}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Утверждение}
 
\theoremstyle{definition} % "Определение"
\newtheorem{corollary}{Следствие}[theorem]
\newtheorem{problem}{Задача}[section]
 
\theoremstyle{remark} % "Примечание"
\newtheorem*{nonum}{Решение}

%%% Программирование
\usepackage{etoolbox} % логические операторы

%%% Страница
\usepackage{extsizes} % Возможность сделать 14-й шрифт
\usepackage{geometry} % Простой способ задавать поля
    \geometry{top=25mm}
    \geometry{bottom=35mm}
    \geometry{left=35mm}
    \geometry{right=20mm}
 %
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Колонтитулы
%   \pagestyle{fancy}
    %\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % Толщина линейки, отчеркивающей верхний колонтитул
%   \lfoot{Нижний левый}
%   \rfoot{Нижний правый}
%   \rhead{Верхний правый}
%   \chead{Верхний в центре}
%   \lhead{Верхний левый}
%   \cfoot{Нижний в центре} % По умолчанию здесь номер страницы

\usepackage{setspace} % Интерлиньяж
%\onehalfspacing % Интерлиньяж 1.5
%\doublespacing % Интерлиньяж 2
%\singlespacing % Интерлиньяж 1

\usepackage{lastpage} % Узнать, сколько всего страниц в документе.

\usepackage{soul} % Модификаторы начертания

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,rgb]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{                % Гиперссылки
    unicode=true,           % русские буквы в раздела PDF
    pdftitle={Заголовок},   % Заголовок
    pdfauthor={Автор},      % Автор
    pdfsubject={Тема},      % Тема
    pdfcreator={Создатель}, % Создатель
    pdfproducer={Производитель}, % Производитель
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % Ключевые слова
    colorlinks=true,        % false: ссылки в рамках; true: цветные ссылки
    linkcolor=red,          % внутренние ссылки
    citecolor=black,        % на библиографию
    filecolor=magenta,      % на файлы
    urlcolor=cyan           % на URL
}

\usepackage{csquotes} % Еще инструменты для ссылок
\usepackage{multicol} % Несколько колонок

\usepackage{tikz} % Работа с графикой

\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\newcommand*{\ham}[1]{#1\nobreak\discretionary{}%
    {\hbox{$\mathsurround=0pt #1$}}{}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\author{\LaTeX{} в Вышке}
\title{5.2.2. Русский язык в \LaTeX: Xe\LaTeX}
\date{\today}

\begin{document} % конец преамбулы, начало документа
    \begin{align*}
     &b_2^\text{МНК} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_n^{i=1}(p_i -\overline p)(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})}{\sum\limits_{n}^{i=1}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{n}^{i=1}([\beta_1 + \beta_2\omega_i + \upsilon_{pi} ]-[\beta_1 + \beta_2\omega_i + \overline\upsilon_{p}])(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})} {\sum\limits_{n}^{i=1}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2}    =\\ =&\dfrac{\sum\limits_{n}^{i=1}(\beta_2(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})+(\upsilon_{pi}- \overline\upsilon_{p} ) (\omega_1 - \overline{\omega}))}{\sum\limits_{n}^{i=1}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2} = \beta_2 + \dfrac{\sum\limits_{n}^{i=1}(\upsilon_{pi}-\overline\upsilon_{p})(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})}{\sum\limits_{n}^{i=1}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2}.\\
        \end{align*} 
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.1
        cm}
         \begin{flushright} $
        (\Upsilon)$
    \end{flushright}
\end{document} % конец документа
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that very simply with `\shortintertext` and `\raggedleft`:

```
 \begin{align*}
 b_2^\text{МНК} & = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(p_i -\overline p)(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}([\beta_1 + \beta_2\omega_i + \upsilon_{pi} ]-[\beta_1 + \beta_2\omega_i + \overline\upsilon_{p}])(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})} {\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2} =\\ 
  & =\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\beta_2(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})+(\upsilon_{pi}- \overline\upsilon_{p} ) (\omega_1 - \overline{\omega}))}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2} = \beta_2 + \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\upsilon_{pi}-\overline\upsilon_{p})(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2}.\\
\shortintertext{\raggedleft$(\Upsilon)$}%
    \end{align*}
```

Unrelated: needless to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`, nor `amsfonts` when you load `amssymb`: both do the job for you. I alsp think you swapped the  positions of `i = 1` and `n` in the sums.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that `(\Upsilon)` is just a number for this equation? Then I'd suggest to use `\tag` for it. This will make LaTeX place it appropriately for any given page width (sometimes it'll go under the equation, sometimes it'll go to the right of the equation).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3.6cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 b_2^\text{МНК} & = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(p_i -\overline p)(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}([\beta_1 + \beta_2\omega_i + \upsilon_{pi} ]-[\beta_1 + \beta_2\omega_i + \overline\upsilon_{p}])(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})} {\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2}=\notag\\ 
  & =\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\beta_2(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})+(\upsilon_{pi}- \overline\upsilon_{p} ) (\omega_1 - \overline{\omega}))}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2} = \beta_2 + \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\upsilon_{pi}-\overline\upsilon_{p})(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\omega_1 - \overline{\omega})^2}.
\tag{$\Upsilon$}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

And for a bit less wide margins (3.3cm, the only change in the code):
[image]